# Interpreting plane waves solutions of the Dirac equation

Tags: momentum, field-theory, fourier-transform, dirac-equation

The Dirac equation $(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\psi = 0$ has plane wave solutions of the form:
$$\psi_{+,k}(t,x) = e^{-iE(k)t+ik\cdot x}u(k) \quad \mbox{and} \quad \psi_{-,k}(t,x) = e^{iE(k)t -ik\cdot x}v(-k)$$
where $k, x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$.

**Question:** The above expressions are functions of $t,x$ for *each fixed* $k$. How do I interpret these solutions? Does it mean that the Dirac equation have solutions with constant well-defined momentum? Each such pair of solutions represent a fermion with constant momentum $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dirac equation is linear, meaning that sums of solutions with arbitrary weights are also solutions.

You can take multiple plane waves with different $k$ and add them together.

Or you can take a distribution in $k$-space and integrate your plane wave over $k$-space weighted by that distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to say that, in physics and field theory, whenever you have a solution to a linear theory which is proportional to $e^{-i k_\mu x^\mu}$ (with maybe some constant n dimensional vector out front) where $k^2 = m^2$, you always interpret this quantum mechanically as a particle of four momentum $k_\mu$. This is justified when you go to quantum field theory, as you can build an oscillator in the mode of this solution with integer occupation numbers.